# Can we give answer in perfect tense when question was asked in simple tense?

Tags: questions

Can we give answer in perfect tense when question was asked in simple tense?

E.g.1.

a) Where did you go this holiday?

Ans: We went to my India this holiday.

I am not sure about below conversation. Both the answers give idea that I was not at home.

E.g. 2

b) I visited your place yesterday, but you were not at home,  where did you go?

Ans a) : Sorry, I went to the mall.

Ans b) : Sorry, I had gone to the mall.

Answer (score 1):

Both work, though the second sounds a bit awkward. And even though it doesn't technically answer the question "Where did you go?" a lot of people would probably answer "Sorry, I was at the mall"